# WIndows is not following TcpAckFrequency settings

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, tcpip, latency

This is a wierd one.
I have set the tcpackfrequency to 2 and windows does not seem to honor it no matter what I do.
I would need your help with this. My current template is Internet and congestion provider set to CTCP.

But I still see windows cumulatively Acking the data. Sometimes upto 20 segments. I want it to be set to 2.
See pcap:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyAlI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Windows TCP implementation is fairly opaque and you will frequently find that not all registry options are supported in all versions of Windows or are overwritten by some other setting.

For reference, when Acknowledgement packets are sent for more than 2 full sized data packets, this is referred to as a Stretch ACK which you can read about here: [RFC 2525](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2525#page-40).